# Iterate a Linq Expression and convert it into DB parameter

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

How i can iterate a Linq Expression and convert it into DB parameter so that i can avoid passing multiple parameter as input to the DAL method

**Business Layer:**
 In BL i have code like this

```
  database.GetProduct(a => a.ProductType == "tea" || a.Price <= 5);
```

In DAL i use plain ADO.Net and want to convert the expression whatever i returned from BL to ADO.Net parameters

**Data Access Layer:**

```
 public DataSet GetProduct(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> pred)
 {

    step 1:
          Iterate the predicate and create new sqlparameter.
    step 2:
      return database.ExecuteDataset(parameters)    
 }
```

How i  can iterate "pred" & convert it to SQLParameter

Comment: Linq provider is doing that, why do you have to repeat it?

Comment: Because i don't use Linq 2 sql / Entity Framework / N Hibernate, I'm using simple ADO.Net

Comment: ^ He's not using a Linq provider, he's using vanilla ADO.NET

Comment: This might make a fun project for a course on compiler theory, but for a production app, I'd adopt LINQ to SQL directly.

Comment: I Wish i could use the providers, but have some constraints to use ADO.Net directly

Comment: LINQ to SQL does use ADO.NET underneath; it uses a standard `IDbConnection`. To make this work you'll need to replicate a lot of the structure of LINQ to SQL -- unless you limit yourself to handling trivial expressions, "step 1" in your example is going to need a lot of code.

Comment: If your not using `LINQ-SQL` or `LINQ-Entities`, why use `LINQ Expressions`? Just pass through the native param types in your BL.

Comment: My search criteria looks well composed & i can pass any number of search criteria in single parameter using Linq expressions.

Comment: I think `database.GetProducts("Type == 'tea' OR Price <= 5");` looks fairly good, although the caller must know about the database.

Comment: @kayak I would have a look at [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) -- it should provide leads, *including code*, if nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matthew writes, you'll need process the expression tree. This can be done using `ExpressionVisitor`, which allows you to write some code for every type of node in the expression tree. However, if you want to support only simple expressions (such as the one in your example), then you could use `NodeType` property to process it.

The structure could be something like:

```
static void HandlePrimitive(Expression e) {
  // TODO: Handle primitive cases (>, <, <=, !=, >=, ..)
  Console.WriteLine(e.NodeType);
}

static void Process(Expression e) {
  if (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.OrElse)
  {
    // Process left subexpression (one (in)equality) as primitive
    // and right subexpression recursively (it may be either primitive 
    // or another OrElse node.
    var be = e as BinaryExpression;
    HandlePrimitive(be.Left);
    Process(be.Right);
  }
  else HandlePrimitive(e);
}

Expression<Func<Product,bool>> f = a => a.ProductType == "tea" || a.Price <= 5;
Process(f.Body);
```

The `Process` method recursively iterates over all the subexpressions composed using the "or" operator (you could support "and" similarly). The `HandlePrimitive` method would deal with expressions that may be composed using `||'s. These are other`BinaryExpression`values (e.g.`Equal`or`LessThanEqual`). You'll need to look at their`Left`and`Right` property to find out the property name and value to be compared against.. but it shouldn't be too much work for this simple type of expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into using the visitor pattern on your expression so you can walk through the expression tree you generate to determine which members to project as parameters.  The [IQToolkit](http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/)  project has a nice `ExpressionVisitor` base class that you could find useful as a base implemenation of the visitor pattern. You could subclass that to handle the `VisitMemberAccess` specifically to deal with your properties.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that one

Comment: Just a comment; the ExpressionVisitor class is built right into .NET 4.

Answer (score -1):

You do not want to go down this road.  You are going to be reimplementing LINQ to SQL.  I might suggest that you use optional arguments:

```
public DataSet GetProduct(int? maxPrice = null, string type = null)
{
    //... snip ...
    if (price.HasValue) whereClause += " OR price <= " + maxPrice";
    //... snip ...
}
```

Comment: If Linq expressions prove tough , i will end up doing like this

Comment: @kayak, it probably won't be too hard to get the simple cases working, but honestly you will be doing a lot of work to reimplement something that Microsoft offers for free.