# C# Action<T>, Pass function as parameter

Tags: c#

I want to pass a condition as Action to another method. First line in "ComputerPriceGenerator" works, but how to make the array work (second line)?.. Any ideas

I'm looking for advice..., CalculateAllPrice is not designed yet

```
public void ComputerPriceGenerator()
{
    //Below line Works
    PriceMachine.CalculatePrice(cart.Computers[0],() => ComputerConverter(cart.Computers[0]));           
    //How to make this work, i don't want to loop it???
    PriceMachine.CalculateAllPrice(cart.Computers,() => ComputerConverter(??));
}

public void ComputerConverter(Computer comp)
{
    if (comp.Memory <= 2)
        comp.Discount = 10;
}
```

Comment: Your code would have been a great candidate to use LINQ, however it is full of side-effects.  I'd consider refactoring.

Comment: Without showing the signatures of CalculatePrice and CalculateAllPrice it's hard to know how to help you.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It seemed like he was looking partly for advice on what the signature of `CalculateAllPrice` should be. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @JonSkeet, @Justin Morgan... I'm looking for advice..., CalculateAllPrice is not designed yet, but for CalculatePrice it takes type Action CalculatePrice(Computer comp, Action myAction)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `CalculatePrice` method *shouldn't* take just `Action`, IMO - both methods should take `Action<Computer>`. So I would have the methods like this:

```
public static void CalculatePrice(Computer computer, Action<Computer> action)
public static void CalcuateAllPrices(IEnumerable<Computer> computers,
                                     Action<Computer> action)
```

and call them like this:

```
PriceMachine.CalculatePrice(cart.Computers[0], ComputerConverter);
PriceMachine.CalculateAllPrice(cart.Computers, ComputerConverter);
```

Comment: Jon, i have a unsolved question(this question is not related to this one, i will delete this) .., Let me know if you have any suggestion " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444972/iterate-a-linq-expression-and-convert-it-into-db-parameter "

Comment: @kayak: The answers there say pretty much what I would. You almost certainly don't want to go down that road.

Comment: Jon, is your second method an example of a monad? I've been trying to wrap my head around what they're all about and how to use them.

Comment: @Justin: No, it's not really a monad IMO - there needs to be rather more involved than just a single method signature, for one thing.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to apply the method to all elements of the array, you won't get around iterating over it.

You could define `PriceMachine.CalculateAllPrice` as such:

```
public void CalculateAllPrice(IEnumerable<Computer> data, Action<Computer> action)
{
  foreach(Computer c in data)
    action(c);
}
```

Comment: i agree but how to pass the Action from main method    "  PriceMachine.CalculateAllPrice(cart.Computers,() => ComputerConverter(??));"

Answer (score 1):

```
PriceMachine.CalculateAllPrice(cart.Computers, (Computer x) => ComputerConverter(x));
```

Then make `CalculateAllPrice` iterate through `cart.Computers` and pass each one to the anonymous function.

Comment: Seems a bit overkill. `(cart.Computers, (Computer x) => ComputerConverter(x))` is the same as `(cart.Computers, ComputerConverter)`.

Comment: @Juliet: Sure, I was just keeping with the lambda style he posted.